# How do I make a program with multiple classes run until the user specifies "E" instead of terminating at the end of Main?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that allows a user to read a file, search for specific text (still in progress) in a file and write (append) to a file. The program has four classes, with one method in each, corresponding to each of the functions of the program.

My first class (containing Main) prompts the user to specify whether they want to read/search/write to a default file. Like so:

```
public class SimpleDBFunction {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        //Prompt user to provide input in accordance with desired function
        System.out.println("Type 'R' to read a file; 'S' to search for text within a file; 'W' to write to a file; 'E' to exit");

        //Initialize scanner and a string variable to hold the value of scanner variable
        Scanner iChoice = new Scanner(System.in);       //iChoice - inputChoice
        String userChoice = iChoice.next();

        //If user specifies "r" go to fileReader class
        if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("r")){
            SimpleDBReader sdbrObject = new SimpleDBReader();
            sdbrObject.sdbReader(args);

        //If user specifies "s" go to textSearch class
        }else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            SimpleDBSearch sdbsObject = new SimpleDBSearch();
            sdbsObject.sdbSearch(args);

        //If user specifies "w" go to fileWriter class
        }else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
            SimpleDBWriter sdbwObject = new SimpleDBWriter();
            sdbwObject.sdbWriter(args);

        //If user specifies "e" terminate program
        }else if(userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        iChoice.close();        //Close scanner, probably redundant here
    }
}
```

The specific issue I have is that I want the program to run in this "state" of awaiting user input, even after the user has already prompted the program to perform one of the actions. I have tried to use both a while loop, and a do-while loop, to achieve this; but both ended up infinitely repeating whichever function the user specifies instead of running it once and returning to main. I also tried to utilize "break" in a few different positions (foolish of me), only to find that it terminates my program completely when it is reached.

I'm still a programming green-horn, so please bear with me. I know that my code isn't the most polished thing around and that there are a multitude of ways to improve it, but what I want is full functionality before I begin improving. If you wish to see the classes pertaining to reading, searching and writing please let me know.

Comment: In the case of the code you have posted, it will exit whether or not your enter `e`, because it gets to the end of `main`.

Comment: probably your while block only included the if() statements, and it should include `// Initailize scanner ` as well

Comment: @AndyTurner That's the issue I'm trying to work out, how to terminate the program only when the user specifies doing so. At the moment my "exit" statement is just sitting there, seeing as it at least terminates a single run-through.

Comment: You need a loop then.

Comment: @AndyTurner I try both a while and a do-while. Both resulted in infinite repetition of whichever function the user specifies

Comment: Please add the while loop to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put `Scanner iChoice = ...` on top
- Put everything between that and `iChoice.close();` into an infinite loop

  - Only the scanner init and scanner close method will be outside this loop
  - `String userChoice = ...` needs to be inside the loop as well

---

A proper implementation would also wrap the loop in a `try` block and close the scanner in `finally`. Also the logic to perform inside the while loop based on user input might be a candidate for a separate method, to keep the try block easy to comprehend.

Comment: It worked! Thank you for clarifying the precedence required to make the loop work. My previous loop attempts were similar, I was  starting them after the initialization of my userChoice variable.